# JQuery - How to delete CSS attributes in Internet Explorer correctly?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'am doing some form validation and noticed that Internet Explorer don't works correctly (as always). If I attach some text and CSS into a div-element and delete it again (when the input is ok) the Explorer doesn't correct the display again. I mean the text gets deleted, but there still remains a blank row (as if there is br-element). I've checked the source-code and the CSS was deleted correctly, but the display isn't correct. Why?

Other browsers have no problems.

```
    if(bla)
    { 
      $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).html("Mindestens 3 Zeichen"); 
      $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).attr("style","color:red; font-size:12px; line-height:12px; position:relative; top:5px; left:25px;");
    }
    else
    { 
      $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).html(""); 
      $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).attr("")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use ".attr()" to set the style property with jQuery 1.6 or newer. Use ".prop()" instead:

```
$("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).prop("")
```

The "style" property is a *property*. IE is very picky about the difference. Use ".prop()" for anything that, when dealing directly with the DOM element un-wrapped by jQuery, you'd treat as an ordinary property of the object: "name", "id", "className", "tagName", etc.

*edit because I'm slow this evening* — that said - and it's all true - the "style" property in particular is not a string-valued property. It's an object in its own right, and setting it to "" doesn't really make sense (to Firefox or IE).  But you *can* zap all the CSS properties:

```
$("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).each(function() {
  for (var cssp in this.style) {
    this.style[cssp] = '';
  }
});
```

*edit again* — hey gang stop upvoting me until I figure out the right answer - this may not work in IE ...

*edit* boy is IE weird ... OK in IE8 this works:

```
$("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).each(function() {
  for (var cssp in this.style) {
    try { this.style[cssp] = null; } catch (who_cares) {}
  }
});
```

It's apparently important to use `null` instead of the empty string; at some point setting something to the empty string caused IE to seize up and spin the CPU for a few seconds.

Comment: Had no effect. But this seems like something which I should keep in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Really??  No effect at all?  Are you sure the selector is working, etc?  The underlying issue is that jQuery (since version 1.6 - are you using something older?) uses the "setAttribute()" native DOM method for ".attr()", and IE treats that as a completely separate namespace from the properties on a DOM element object.

Comment: Nope, no effect in any case that I've tried. Selector is working right, also the attribute .. urr.. property gets correctly deleted. The version of JQuery is 1.7.1

Comment: OK answer updated.  Sorry for wasting your time :-). Also thanks for accepting anyway :-)

Comment: Crap except that STILL doesn't work in IE.  I'm starting to agree with your assessment of IE and its developers. Hold on a sec and I'll see if I can find the answer ...

Comment: The added solution ratherly also doesn't work (also no effect) Frustrating problem. It's not that important to fix that for me, so stop bothering yourself if you want :) Big thanks for your effort.

Comment: OK I updated it again.  Tonight I learned another reason to dislike Internet Explorer :-)

Comment: Also the third solution does not works, no matter how I try. Ok, I give it up. Thank you very much for your help, there were some good insights.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.attr("")` won't delete the style, as you haven't specified what attribute to change. Use `.attr("style", "")` to clear the style attribute.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tvL42/2/

Side note: You don't need to create a new jQuery object to set the HTML and the style, just chain the calls:

```
if(bla) { 
  $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index)
    .html("Mindestens 3 Zeichen") 
    .attr("style","color:red; font-size:12px; line-height:12px; position:relative; top:5px; left:25px;");
} else { 
  $("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index)
    .html("") 
    .attr("style", "");
}
```

Comment: Right, thanks. But it also doesn't solve the problem. Also thanks the side note.

Comment: Ok, then try to hide the entire element instead of just emptying it: `$("div[bez='avz_kw_err']").eq(index).hide();`

Comment: Wooow!! It f***ing works this way. Can't believe it, thanks :)